# CALayer setNeedsDisplayInRect - what is the point of InRect? Or faster drawing in drawInContext

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I have a CALayer (imageLayer), and a subclassed CALayer that acts as a mask on the CALayer (maskLayer).

I am painting with a finger onto the maskLayer so that I can temporarily erase out part of the imageLayer.

I am accomplishing this by keeping one Bitmap Context (maskContext), and adding a stroke to it in touchesMoved. So my maskContext just holds all the strokes I have painted. In touchesMoved, I do `[maskLayer setNeedsDisplay]`;

in my subclassed maskLayer, I have the `drawInContext` method:

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(maskContext);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image);
}
```

This all works out really well, but is very slow as it's drawing the whole view for each touchesMoved event.

I thought of using `[maskLayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect]` but I wondered what the point is, as `drawInContext` does not look at the rect. I could pass the rect to `drawInContext`, but I could do that with just `setNeedsDisplay`.

Is there something that `setNeedsDisplayInRect` does that `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't for a CALayer?

(I am aware that if I were using `drawRect`, that would accept the defined rect, but a CALayer's `drawInContext` doesn't)

Also, is there any better way of accomplishing this masking by painting with a finger? The main problem is that the CGContext is not a canvas and does not remember previous strokes, so they have to be redrawn all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark a layer to display by calling `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` then you can use `CGContextGetClipBoundingBox` to get the area marked to display in your `drawInContext:`.

Comment: Thank you SO much for this! I've been going barmy trying to make NSView perform the functions that CALayer was designed for. Now if I can just clear up the problems I'm having with implicit animation, I'll be golden :)